# Check less or equal natural number in coq

Tags: coq

I have function (`beq_nat_refl`) which determines the equality of two natural numbers and gives a boolean. But now I want to prove a lemma stating that a natural number `x` is less or equal to `x`. 
May I use the above function (`beq_nat_refl`)?

```
Theorem beq_nat_refl : 
  forall n : nat,
    true = beq_nat n n.

Theorem leq_nat :
  forall x:nat,
    x <= x.
```

Comment: Why would `beq_nat_refl` be of any use? You can just use `constructor` to prove your theorem I think.

Answer (score 1):

That would work if you would define `x <= y` as `x < y || x == y`; however this is not the definition, so usually the proof of `x <= x` tends to be induction [on the computational case] or by applying the base constructor if using a witness.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straightforward path to proving `leq_nat` from similar definitions:

```
Fixpoint leb (n m : nat) : bool :=
  match n, m with
  | 0  , _   => true
  | _  , 0   => false
  | S n, S m => leb n m
  end.

Lemma leb_nat_refl : forall (n : nat), leb n n = true.
Proof.
  induction n; simpl.
  + reflexivity.
  + assumption.
Qed.

Lemma leb_nat_reflect : forall (n : nat), leb n n = true <-> n <= n.
Proof.
  induction n; simpl; split; intros.
  + constructor.
  + reflexivity.
  + constructor.
  + apply IHn. constructor.
Qed.

Theorem leq_nat : forall (n : nat), n <= n.
Proof.
  intros.
  apply leb_nat_reflect.
  apply leb_nat_refl.
Qed.
```